# Typescript with Polymer 1.0?

Tags: typescript, polymer, typescript1.5

I found this great article I had been using with Polymer 0.5 ( http://www.mikecann.co.uk/programming/tinkering-with-google-polymer-and-typescript/ ) for being able to use Typescript Classes for Polymer Elements. This approach no longer works with Polymer 1.0 . I tried

```
class CreatorStudio extends Polymer.Class({}) {

  is = "creator-studio";
}

/*(function () {
Polymer(CreatorStudio.prototype);
})();*/
document.registerElement("creator-studio", CreatorStudio.prototype);
```

And a number of other approaches but can't seem to get the element to register the same as Polymer({is: "creator-studio"});

Anyone been able to get TS classes and Polymer 1.0 to play together?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use the package [PolymerTS](https://github.com/nippur72/PolymerTS)

Comment: **PolymerTS** is very helpful to work with Polymer using Typescript.  I wrote also a Yeoman generator **[generator-polymerts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-polymerts)** to make easier work with it

Comment: Thanks for writing PolymerTS, it's great. I wrote [an article about using it and several other tools together](http://blog.charto.net/typescript/Taming-Polymer-with-SystemJS-and-TypeScript-part-1/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
class CreatorStudio extends Polymer.Class(
    {
        is: "creator-studio",
        properties: {}
    }
){
    ready() {
        // ...
    }
    created(){
        // ...
    }
```

and later:

```
document.registerElement(CreatorStudio.prototype.is, CreatorStudio);
```

Here's a working sample (although using Babel, not Typescript):
http://codepen.io/mikkokam/pen/jPMLJN

Comment: How come [[model.fullname]] reflects updates to input field - typically [[..]] represents an unchanging initial value.