# How can I get typings when I import a js library with a `<script src`... tag?

Tags: javascript, typescript, polymer, typescript-typings

I'm using polymer to import external javascript libraries that export as a global variable like so:

```
<script src="/path/to/library"></script>
<script>
    theLibrary.something // `theLibrary` is a global exported from the script tag above
</script>
```

I'm a bit new to polymer and I've been previously working in a typescript environment, so long story short: I miss my typings.

Is there anyway to get the typings inside the `<script>` tags of the HTML or get typings any way at all in a Polymer element?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541419/typescript-with-polymer-1-0 maybe this will help you out?

Comment: @Deathstorm thank you, but I'm not sure that will help. To clarify, I'm not trying to use polymer with typescript. I'm trying to use typings (written in typescript) with polymer. The polymer elements I write will still be ultimately be written in javascript, [the typings just help](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/05/19/using-typescripts-type-definition-files-to-get-tooling-support-for-plain-javascript).

Comment: Ohh okay, thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: You can try a reference directive:  `/// <reference path="Script.js" />`  This should tell Intellisense to source from that JS file.  You can't use TypeScript typings here, since this isn't a TS file.